# llc -view-*-dags foo.ll not working in ubuntu

Tags: llvm, graphviz, llc

I have installed LLVM3.6 on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I have also set the path for 
`LLVM_PATH_DOT=/usr/bin/dot` and later on `LLVM_PATH_DOT=/usr/bin/dotty`.

I also tried to check `LLVM_ENABLE_DOXYGEN` during CMake configuration, and gave the path for DOTTY. It also doesn't work.

Lastly, I created a new entry in CMAKE, called `LLVM_PATH_DOTTY`, and supplied in the path. It also doesn't work.

When I try to create the DAG output for a .ll file, llc neither gives any error message nor prints a graph.

I pass in the following command:

```
llc -view-dag-combine-lt-dags foo.ll
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using LLVM 3.6.x or earlier, you have to also specify the `-filter-view-dags=<bb-name>` option to specify the name of the basic block which you wish to view.

This was unintended behaviour (omitting the flag is meant to mean "view all basic blocks", not "view none of the basic blocks"). The bug was fixed in LLVM 3.7. If you want to manually apply the patch which fixes this, see this mailing list post for details: http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2015-July/088631.html